# javascript function affect a class with many elements without affecting on a spesific class

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'am trying to develop a function to affect a class which has many elements in it. But I don't want that js function to effect on a specific class which is also an element in that previously mentioned class.
The thing is when I run that project as a html document simply on the browser, the code I've got works perfectly fine. But when I convert it to jade and run through node js the console error says a bracket is missing after the argument and it does not work too. I think its supposed to work as it does when I test the code using the html file.The path spesifications and hrefs are all correct. I've tested them.
the js code I've got

```
$window.on('load', function() {

    $('.thumbnails:not('bton')').poptrox({
        onPopupClose: function() { $body.removeClass('is-covered'); },
        onPopupOpen: function() { $body.addClass('is-covered'); },
        baseZIndex: 10001,
        useBodyOverflow: false,
        usePopupEasyClose: true,
        overlayColor: '#000000',
        overlayOpacity: 0.75,
        popupLoaderText: '',
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
        windowMargin: (skel.breakpoint('small').active ? 5 : 50)
    });

});
```

I tried changing the quotations to double quotations and single quotations in every possible way. Please be kind enough to point my mistake here. Thank you in advance

Edit : 
html sample of my page.

```
<section class="thumbnails">
    <div>
        <a href="images/thumbs/OG1.jpg">
            <img src="images/thumbs/OG1.jpg" alt="" />
            <h3>Description</h3>
        </a>
        <a class="bton" href="#"><b>Click Here &nbsp</b><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: if `bton` is a variable, it has to be `$('.thumbnails:not(' + bton + ')')`

Comment: thumbnails is the class of the section. it includes divs images anchor tags and stuff. bton is a class ive given for some anchor tags. I want the function to affect the thumbnails class and all other classes inside that section except for the tags with bton class. This code works well when I test it without using the localhost

Answer (score 0):

> bton is a class ive given for some anchor tags

In this case your selector should be

```
$('.thumbnails:not(.bton)')
```

Comment: @AchalaWeerasooriya what do you mean by  `It does not work like that`?

Comment: I checked your answer. and it did not work. I mean now my selector is `$('.thumbnails:not(.bton)').poptrox({` but the function still affects the bton class

Comment: @AchalaWeerasooriya in that case try `$('.thumbnails').not('.bton')`

Comment: @gurvinder327 It seems like when I use not, the function does not affect the thumbnails class even. When I remove not it affects the thumbnails class.

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont you use your code like these,

```
 $window.on('load', function() {

    $('.thumbnails:not (.bton)').poptrox({
        onPopupClose: function() { $body.removeClass('is-covered'); },
        onPopupOpen: function() { $body.addClass('is-covered'); },
        baseZIndex: 10001,
        useBodyOverflow: false,
        usePopupEasyClose: true,
        overlayColor: '#000000',
        overlayOpacity: 0.75,
        popupLoaderText: '',
        fadeSpeed: 500,
        usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
        windowMargin: (skel.breakpoint('small').active ? 5 : 50)
    });

});
```

Comment: It too does not work. When I use this code it stops affecting any class inside thumbnails class

Comment: i still not understand why are you using .thumbnails:not here? is there any specific requirement for it?

Comment: What I want to do is something like this. example: 
<section class="thumbnails">
<div><img><a><h3></h3></a><a class="bton"></a>
</section>
In here I want the js function to affect everything inside the section except the anchor tag with class bton. 
I used `$('.thumbnails:not(.bton)')` in every possible way and even tried `$('.thumbnails').not('.bton)` but neither works

Comment: Please can you edit your question, add html and css and jquery if any, then and then developers can resolve it...

Comment: if you have to do something like that $(".thumbnails > a:not(.bton) ") not proper one but it will help you..

Comment: No sir. I'am still at the place where it started. What this function does is it opens a popup window when the image image is clicked and when the button is clicked I want to href to another link. What happens now is if the selector is like `$('.thumbnails:not(.bton)')` the pop up works when either of the image or the button is clicked. When I change the selector to anything else except the above, the button click works but the popup does not come. It opens the image in the browser itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108495/discussion-between-bharat-and-achala-weerasooriya).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".thumbnails, .thumbnails *:not(a.bton)").poptrox(...);
```

You need `.thumbnails` by itself to select the whole section, and then `.thumbnails *:not(a.bton)` selects all elements within the section except the anchor with `class="bton"`.

Comment: No Still the same :(

Comment: What does `poptrox` do? It seems unlikely that you really want it applied to every element in the section.